# Tkinter ignores Canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Why Tkinter ignores my canvas and m_text label appears just in a root window?

```
import tkinter as tk


    backg = '#06090f'
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Simple program')
    #root.geometry('600x300')
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=900, width=600, bg=backg)
    canvas.grid(column=0, row=0)
    m_text = tk.Label(canvas, text='Hello')
    m_text.grid(column=0, row=0)
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I've noticed that when I comment the lines:

```
m_text = tk.Label(canvas, text='Hello')
m_text.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

The canvas appears as told.

Comment: This is not how you place stuff inside of the canvas, you use `create_window()`.

Comment: The canvas is there, it simply shrunk to fit it's children, which is what all tkinter widgets do when you add children to it with `pack` or `grid`.  It's very unusual to use `grid` to add a widget to a canvas. You won't be able to scroll it, for example. What are you trying to accomplish by using `grid` to add the label to the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Putting
`m_text`
in the same grid
location as the canvas overrides the canvas.
Try:

```
m_text.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why Tkinter ignores my canvas

You are setting `canvas.grid` on `column=0`, which is in the top left corner. So that is why you can't see on canvas.

If you set `column` to 1, then use `ipdax` greater than 50, then you can see on the `canvas` widget.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


backg = '#06090f'
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Simple program')
#root.geometry('600x300')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=900, width=600, bg=backg)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0, ipadx=50) #<--- Add this
m_text = tk.Label(canvas, text='Hello')
m_text.grid(column=0, row=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]